# Send email via MATLAB

Tags: matlab, email, sendmail

I need to send an email via MATLAB and I've read the instructions for sendmail and lots of answers around here. I've tried 3 email providers and I can't really use any of them:

- Gmail: I can only send email when I deactivate my anivirus
- Hotmail and Yahoo: *Error using sendmail (line 171) Exception reading response; Connection reset*
- Hotmail and Yahoo (antivirus off): *Error using sendmail (line 171) Exception reading response; Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection?*

---

Here's the code

```
mail = 'user@service.com'; 
password = 'passwordgoeshere';
setpref('Internet','SMTP_Server','smtp.server.com');
setpref('Internet','E_mail',mail);
setpref('Internet','SMTP_Username',mail);
setpref('Internet','SMTP_Password',password);
props = java.lang.System.getProperties;
props.setProperty('mail.smtp.auth','true');
props.setProperty('mail.smtp.socketFactory.class', 'javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory');
props.setProperty('mail.smtp.socketFactory.port',port);
sendmail(mail,'Test from MATLAB','Hello! This is a test from MATLAB!')
```

---

I've used the following variables:

- Gmail: smtp.gmail.com port=465
- Hotmail: smtp.live.com port=465 and port=587
- Yahoo: smtp.mail.yahoo.com port=587

---

Since deactivating the antivirus is not a good option, can anyone help me solving this?

Thank you

Comment: Have you tried allowing MATLAB through your antivirus firewall? (i.e., making an exception)

Comment: Yes... still getting this error:
Error using sendmail (line 171)
Exception reading response;
sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed:
sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested
target

Comment: Not clear if this is related to your particular error, but one possible source of problems with `sendmail` may be related to Java trying to use IPV6.  See: http://www.mathworks.co.uk/matlabcentral/answers/103835-why-do-i-get-a-permission-denied-when-i-use-sendmail-in-matlab-r2013b-prerelease

Answer (score 0):

An alternative way on linux is to run a command line that send the email.

```
unix('echo "message" | mail -s "subject" example@gmail.com');
```

A similar method should be available for windows.

Answer (score 0):

**For Gmail**

Change your settings to allow less secure apps to access your account. Go to the "Less secure apps" section in My Account.
Next to "Access for less secure apps," select Turn on. (Note to Google Apps users: This setting is hidden if your administrator has locked less secure app account access.)

**In Matlab:**

```
mail = 'user@otherdomain.com';
password = 'myPassword';

% Set up the preferences
setpref('Internet','E_mail',mail);
setpref('Internet','SMTP_Server','smtp.gmail.com');
setpref('Internet','SMTP_Username',mail);
setpref('Internet','SMTP_Password',password);

% The following is necessary only if you are using GMail as
% your SMTP server. 
props = java.lang.System.getProperties;
props.setProperty('mail.smtp.auth','true');
props.setProperty('mail.smtp.socketFactory.class', 'javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory');
props.setProperty('mail.smtp.socketFactory.port','465');

subject = 'Test subject';
message = 'Test message';

sendmail(mail,subject,message)
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply declare

```
mail = 'user';
```

Drop the extension *@service.com* for the variable `mail`.