# Send Emails from an Gmail account via MATLAB R2015a

Tags: java, matlab, email, gmail

I want to send emails from MATLAB R2015a using my Gmail account. Here is my code:

```
mail = 'username@gmail.com'; %Your GMail email address
password = 'userpassword';  %Your GMail password
setpref('Internet','SMTP_Server','smtp.gmail.com');
setpref('Internet','E_mail',mail);
setpref('Internet','SMTP_Username',mail);
setpref('Internet','SMTP_Password',password);


props = java.lang.System.getProperties;
props.setProperty('mail.smtp.auth','true');
props.setProperty('mail.smtp.socketFactory.class', 'javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory');
props.setProperty('mail.smtp.socketFactory.port','465');


% Send the test email to yourself.
sendmail(mail,'Test from MATLAB','Hello! This is a test from MATLAB!')
```

After turning on "access from less secure apps" from Google account setting as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36385308/4448408) suggests, I still get the following error message.

> Error using sendmail (line 171)
>   Exception reading response;
>   sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid
>   certification path to requested target
>
> Error in sendemail (line 25)
>   sendmail(mail,'Test from MATLAB','Hello! This is a test from MATLAB!')

Is there another way to solve this certification issue?

Comment: Hmm... I can't reproduce your problem. This code works for me as-is (on MATLAB R2016a + Java 1.7.0_60-b19) after supplying a valid user/pass. For this reason I think it's not a problem with MATLAB, but rather your Network/OS/Java/Gmail settings.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. The two machines that I tried this code and failed are Windows 10 Java build 1.8.0_91-b14 and Windows 7 build 1.8.0_31-b13 respectively. Do you know which setting I should check further to solve this issue?

Comment: The Java version that you mentioned are the ones **MATLAB** uses, or ones that you happen to have installed on your systems?

Comment: The Java versions mentioned before are the versions installed in the system. MATLAB uses Java 1.7.0_60-b19. Sorry about the confusion.